# C# gRPC client - name resolution failure

Tags: grpc

A client is running our C# gRPC client on a corporate network, behind an HTTP proxy. The `http_proxy` environment variable is configured, but nevertheless he sees an error message `Name resolution failure` when attempting to connect to the server on the internet.

DNS resolution from the same machine works fine using nslookup.

Any ideas what I can do to investigate this problem?

Comment: you can try collecting more detailed logs on what's going wrong in the grpc stack by following instructions in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md. Also providing the logs of nslookup might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following three lines at application startup to configure the detailed logging that @JanTattermusch suggested:

```cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_TRACE", "api");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_VERBOSITY", "debug");
Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.SetLogger(new Grpc.Core.Logging.ConsoleLogger());
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect a C# gRPC client on a corporate network, behind an HTTP proxy, add this on the client main method works:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("NO_PROXY", "127.0.0.1");
```